# How can I remove unwanted data from error JSON in ABP

Tags: c#, exception, abp

I configured ABP with the following options:

```
Configure<AbpExceptionHandlingOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SendExceptionsDetailsToClients = false;
    options.SendStackTraceToClients = false;
});
```

But still I have some unwanted `data` in the error JSON like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": null,
        "message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
        "details": null,
        **"data": {
            "HelpLink.ProdName": "Microsoft SQL Server",
            "HelpLink.EvtSrc": "MSSQLServer",
            "HelpLink.EvtID": "4060",
            "HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink",
            "HelpLink.LinkId": "20476"
        },**
        "validationErrors": null
    }
}
```

How can I remove `data` and its subset from the response JSON.

I tried to find a way to filter Unhandled exceptions or something like that in ABP. In my solution, unfortunately I have a lot of unhandled exceptions and I should have a canonical point to catch them and prevent data leakage in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to maliming. We can override the `DefaultExceptionToErrorInfoConverter` and remove data from the `RemoteServiceErrorInfo`. In fact, in this way, we have better control to generate customized error JSON depending on different exception types and our security concerns.

for more information you can see this issue on ABP Github: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/17949

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `IExceptionToErrorInfoConverter` to filter message.All error message must use this interface to convert to string. it may by help you .

```
//This is Core Code
      private async Task HandleAndWrapException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception)
  {
      _logger.LogException(exception);

      await httpContext
          .RequestServices
          .GetRequiredService<IExceptionNotifier>()
          .NotifyAsync(
              new ExceptionNotificationContext(exception)
          );

      if (exception is AbpAuthorizationException)
      {
          await httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAbpAuthorizationExceptionHandler>()
              .HandleAsync(exception.As<AbpAuthorizationException>(), httpContext);
      }
      else
      {
          var errorInfoConverter = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IExceptionToErrorInfoConverter>();
          var statusCodeFinder = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpExceptionStatusCodeFinder>();
          var jsonSerializer = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IJsonSerializer>();
          var exceptionHandlingOptions = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AbpExceptionHandlingOptions>>().Value;

          httpContext.Response.Clear();
          httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCodeFinder.GetStatusCode(httpContext, exception);
          httpContext.Response.OnStarting(_clearCacheHeadersDelegate, httpContext.Response);
          httpContext.Response.Headers.Add(AbpHttpConsts.AbpErrorFormat, "true");
          httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

          await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
              jsonSerializer.Serialize(
                  new RemoteServiceErrorResponse(
                      errorInfoConverter.Convert(exception, options =>
                      {
                          options.SendExceptionsDetailsToClients = exceptionHandlingOptions.SendExceptionsDetailsToClients;
                          options.SendStackTraceToClients = exceptionHandlingOptions.SendStackTraceToClients;
                      })
                  )
              )
          );
      }
  }
```

Comment: I found a better way to handle this issue. Thanks to Maliming. you can find the solution in the link. https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/17949